# How to add a difficulty to a Javascript hangman game

Tags: javascript

I want to allow the user to select the difficulty of the game. Easy is words length 3-5, Medium is length 6-9, Hard is 10-15. The word is being pulled from an AJAX API. Also, I've consulted this example but am still struggling to apply it to my own. I included extra code because I'm not sure if I could add radio buttons that store the level and word.length that then updates the word retrieved from the api to be the correct length.

```
var api = 'https://hangman-api.lively.software';

//add alphabet to div
alphabet.forEach((i) => {
        $('.hangman-letters').append(`<div id="letter-${i}">${i}</div>`);
    });

//set up initial puzzle
newPuzzle();

//set up new puzzle when user clicks "start over"
$('#game-over-replay').click(function(){
    newPuzzle();
});

//trigger game on clicking letter button
$('.hangman-letters div').click(function(){
    submitLetter(this.innerHTML, this);
});

//trigger game on keypress
$(window).keypress(function(e){
    var thisKey = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if(alpha.indexOf(thisKey) > -1) {
        submitLetter(thisKey, document.getElementById(`letter-${thisKey}`));
    }
})

//functions

//handle clicked letter or keyboard input
function submitLetter(letter, thisLetterButton) {
    var isCorrect = letterChosen(letter);
    if(isCorrect) $(thisLetterButton).addClass('disabled correct');
    else $(thisLetterButton).addClass('disabled');
    if(remainingBlanks < 1) {
        gameOver(true);
    }
    if(totalIncorrect >= hangmanParts.length + 1) {
        gameOver(false);
    }
}

//wipe variables and containers and set up new game
//now called after api call is complete
function setUp(){
    $('.game-over').hide();
    puzzleLetterContainers = [];
    previouslyChosen = '';
    totalIncorrect = 0;
    remainingBlanks = puzzle.length;
    $('.hangman-puzzle').html('');
    $('#added-parts').html('');
    $('.hangman-letters div').each(function(){
        this.classList = '';
    })

    puzzle.split('').forEach((i) => {
        var thisClass = "hangman-puzzle-letters",
                placeholder = "&nbsp;";
        if(i == ' ' || i == '-') {
            thisClass += ' space';
            remainingBlanks--;
            placeholder = i;
        }
        $('.hangman-puzzle').append(`<div class="${thisClass}">${placeholder}</div>`);
    });
    //var difficulty[] = new difficulty;
    //var difficulty[1] = Easy;
    //var difficulty[2] = Medium;
    //var difficulty[3] = Hard;
    puzzleLetterContainers = document.getElementsByClassName('hangman-puzzle-letters');
}
```

Comment: Which part do you need help with?

Comment: Depends on what that API can do/output. If it doesn't have options like setting word length or returning more than one word at a time you will have to call the api repeatedly. Til you got the word that fits the difficulty or to gather enough words to build a collection you can choose from.

Comment: is there no way to just include it in a query string?

Comment: yes in theory. but if the server doesn't actually support that feature then it's useless. You can provide any parameter you want but it will just ignore it or throw an error if it's not expecting it. Is it your API, can you change it to allow you specify a difficulty option? Or does it already support that, and you're asking us how to append that to the URL? It's unclear, especially since we can't even see the AJAX and we have no idea what API you're referring to, and no way of knowing what it's capable of. You need it to be able to return words of the right length in response to your request

Comment: It already supports it and I'm asking us how to append the URL. The API is included in the code at the very top?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. But you're not showing us how you actually make a call to it. Show us the AJAX code, and point out which variable from your big pile of code you want to append to it, and tell us what the parameter should be called (according to the API's documentation...which you also didn't provide a link to...please don't make the volunteers trying to help you have to go hunting round the internet to understand what you're doing :-)).